# function pointer array with class functions of different classes

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

In **SomeClass.h**

```
class SomeClass{
    public:
        static std::vector<void (*)()> UpdateFuncs;
}
```

In **OtherClass.h**

```
class OtherClass{
    private:
        void Update();
    public:
        OtherClass();
}
```

In **OtherClass.cpp**

```
OtherClass::OtherClass(){
    Time::UpdateFuncs.push_back(&(this->Update));
}
```

On Build I get `'&':` illegal operation on bound member function expression
and if I do:

```
.push_back(&Update);
```

Then I get "no instance of overloaded function

> std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=void (*)(), _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list"

Thank in advance

Comment: `&Update` is not a `void (*)()`. This code can't work. What is your question?

Comment: My Question is how to change Update to make is work

Comment: You'd have to make `Update` `static` to get that type.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? `Update` is a non-static member, it has an implicit `this` argument. How do you expect to provide it at the call site?

Answer (score 1):

`OtherClass::Update` is not suitable for a `void (*)()` function pointer, because it's a non-static member function; it's as if it had an "invisible" `OtherClass*` parameter.

Use `std::function` to achieve your goal:

```
#include <functional>

class Time
{
public:
    static std::vector<std::function<void()>> UpdateFuncs;
};
```

In OtherClass.cpp, use a `this`-capturing lamba as a function object:

```
OtherClass::OtherClass()
{
    Time::UpdateFuncs.push_back([this] { Update(); });
}
```

Of course, if you make `Update` static, then you can still work with `void (*)()` if you want to, because the "invisible" parameter is removed, but `std::function` is just the safe and modern way to do it.

Comment: Excellent ! I didn't realize immediately that OP wanted not only the function pointer but also the target object.  I have only one question:  every created `OtherClass` will have a function referencing it in the vector; but how can you find back the entries that correspond to an object that is to be deleted in order to remove it from the vector ?

Comment: @Christophe: That question is too broad... it depends entirely on the rest of the program logic if, how, when and by whom objects are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

You try to assign to an ordinary function pointer of type `void(*)()` a member function pointer of type `void(OtherClass::*)()`.

Unfortunately these two types are incompatible: an ordinary function can be called with only its parameters, and a member function pointer can only be called for a specific object.

### First solution : member function pointer

You have to change the definition of the vector to make it use a member function pointer.

```
class OtherClass;  // forward deaclaration
class SomeClass {
public:
    static std::vector<void (OtherClass::*)()> UpdateFuncs;
};
```

Then you can pushback the function as expected:

```
OtherClass::OtherClass() {
    SomeClass::UpdateFuncs.push_back(&OtherClass::Update);
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/UpStn4)

Unfortunately you can't mix it with member function pointers to other classes or ordinary function pointers.  And you have to specify the object to use at the moment you invoke your function.

### Better solution: command pattern

The **[command pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html)** allows you more flexibility than function pointers.  Thanks to specialization of commands, you can mix commands that will invoke ordinary function pointers, member function pointers of different classes, or ad-hoc functions.

The commands could look like this:

```
class Command {
public: 
    virtual void execute() = 0; 
    virtual ~Command();
}; 

class CommandOtherClass : public Command { 
    OtherClass *target; 
    void (OtherClass::*f)(); 
public: 
    CommandOtherClass (void (OtherClass::*fct)(), OtherClass*t); 
    void execute() override; 
};
```

The implementation is really straightforward:

```
CommandOtherClass::CommandOtherClass (void (OtherClass::*fct)(), OtherClass*t) 
    :  f(fct),target(t) 
{
} 
void CommandOtherClass::execute() {
    (target->*f)();
}
```

The SomeClass function could be changed as follows:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    static std::vector<unique_ptr<Command>> UpdateFuncs;
    static void executeAll();
};
```

Note that you could develop it so to include a registration and unregistration functions, so that you can also remove from the vector commands involving objects that no longer exist.

Adding a new command to the vector would be done like this:

```
OtherClass::OtherClass() {
    SomeClass::UpdateFuncs.push_back(make_unique<CommandOtherClass>(&OtherClass::Update, this));
}
```

Finally, here a complete **[online demo](https://ideone.com/xsFdlt)** that invokes two commands automatically registered for some local objects, and even add a third ad hoc command unrelated to any other object.

Comment: While this is 100% true, the error shown in the question arise actually because `&(this->Update)` should be `*OtherClass::Update`.

Comment: @Holt  Yes, I've edited and added some code to make it clearer